# How do I get user input into a PackageMaker package?

Tags: macos, deployment, packagemaker

I'm trying to create an install package. I've got all my components, and I think I understand most of the process. I want to have an install/set-up script that is run as part of the install. I planned to put it either as a post-install action or a post-install script.

The problem is that I need user-input. I can't figure out how to either get user input into the script, or how to add a page in the install UI that has a place for user input and then pass that on to the script.

I guess, I could write an apple-script with a dialog to ask the question, and then pass that information on to my shell script (or, write the whole thing in the applescript) but that seems unnecessarily complicated...

Is there a normal way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to how the user input collected from the UI can be passed to a script?

Answer (score 5):

You can create an Installer Plug-in, which is a Cocoa loadable bundle that can contain your own user interface and code. When you add a plug-in to the Installer package, the Installer app will display your plug-in's UI as an additional step in the installation process.

The Apple sample code and only available documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/InstallerPluginSample/Introduction/Intro.html). There is a great explanation of the process [here](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Installer_Plugins/index.html).

Unfortunately, inserting the plug-in bundle into your installer package has become needlessly difficult as of PackageMaker 3.0 and its flat package format.

Once you've created your plug-in bundle, you first need to build your installer package as normal. Once it's built, you need to go to the **Edit** menu in PackageMaker and open the **Flat Package Editor**. Open your installer bundle, and insert the plug-in in the appropriate location as you would in the Finder with a 2.0 installer bundle. That is, you need to create a **Plugins** folder and inside that you must insert your bundle plus the **InstallerSections.plist** file (which the sample above explains).

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on this at all?  I've copied those two "files" into a Plugins directory via the  Flat Package Editor like you said.  However, after saving, closing, and re-opening the package, the plugins directory is gone.

Comment: I switched to using Packages instead of PackageMaker and this issue went away.