# How to pass data to a file while Package installation on mac

Tags: python, macos, package, py2app, packagemaker

I am making an app in python. Using python 2.7 on mac osx 10.8.5. I converted python code into an app using py2app. Then I converted myapp.app into package myapp.pkg using Packages.
I am using a configuration file which I kept in Contents-->Resources-->config.cfg. config.cfg file contains data which is necessary for running of app.

`My issue is how to pass serverIP and serverPort to config.cfg file while installing myapp through myapp.pkg i.e. through Packages`. My config.cfg file is like key-value pair.I am using config.parsar to read config.cfg file.

```
[KMS]
serverIP1 = 
serverPort1 =
serverIP2 =
serverPort2 =
```

I need to pass these value to config.cfg file while installing package.The installer should ask these values and the user should input these values.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to write a `packagemaker plugin` that will ask these details from the user and then save it to some file. Then during installation, from a post-install script, you can read this file and modify your config file.

However, it is bad idea to keep such config files inside the app file. A better place for such files is `~/Library/Preferences` or `~/Library/Application Support`.

Tutorials for creating packagemaker plugin: (Requires Cocoa knowledge)
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.06/InstallerPlugins/index.html
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Installer_Plugins/

Comment: Sir, how to write packagemaker plugin, is I have to work on something like GUI window also for asking user input details. Actually I have to distribute this app to others also, thats why I am keeping config file inside app.

Comment: I have posted some links above.

Comment: how to save the data entered by the user during installation in a file.